# SSRS Pivot data in a table with a query

Tags: reporting-services, pivot

I have a dataset with Column 1: Year as an integer (2011, 2012, and 2013) and Column 2: KPI as an index (0-100).

I would like to report the data like a matrix with KPI in rows and Years in columns. One column for each of the 3 years. 
For that pupose the matrix option is fine.

However, I would like to ad a 4. column that shows the development from 2012 to 2013 with an indicator (Negativ is red, neutral is yellow and positive development is green).

In Sql i would just pivot my data in the following way:

```
SELECT  KPI,    
        AVG(case when [year] = 2013 then indeks ELSE NULL end) as [2013], 
        AVG(case when [year] = 2012 then indeks ELSE NULL end) as [2012],
        AVG(case when [year] = 2011 then indeks ELSE NULL end) as [2011]
from    KVI_overblik
Group BY KPI
order BY KPI
```

And then i would make the calculation (KPI.2013 - KPI.2012) in a 4. column.

How can I make the indeks in a SSRS query? In order to design a manual table without using the matrix.

OR have can i make the 4. column if I continue with the matrix?

Looking forward to hear your answers.

Best regars.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with a matrix. In the matrix i added a row total. This total is a sum of all the row values. 
Therefore I had to edit my expression in the new row total coulmn:

```
=IIF(
(isnothing(avg(IIF(Fields!year.Value="2012",Fields!indeks.Value,nothing)))) or (isnothing(avg(IIF(Fields!year.Value="2013",Fields!indeks.Value,nothing))))
,nothing
,
 avg(IIF(Fields!year.Value="2013",Fields!indeks.Value,nothing))
-avg(IIF(Fields!year.Value="2012",Fields!indeks.Value,nothing))

)
```

I only want the latest development 2013 result compared to 2012 result. The expression calculates the development.

Finally, I inserted an Indicator in my calculated field.